# How do I properly set types for higher-order class components in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a utility function that takes a (now unused) options parameter and returns a higher-order component wrapping function.

How do I properly set types on the component to let users of the wrapped component see the types for the underlying, wrapped component as well as the additional context type from the `withAppContext` higher-order component?

```
type AppContext = {
  id: string;
};

const withAppContext = (opts) => {
  const hoc = WrappedComponent => {
    class WithAppContext extends React.Component<any, any> {
      static contextTypes = {
        appContext: PropTypes.shape({
          id: PropTypes.string,
        }),
      };

      context: AppContext;

      render() {
        return React.createElement(WrappedComponent, {
          ...this.props,
          ...this.context
        });
      }
    }
    return WithAppContext;
  };
  return hoc;
};
```

When extending just `React.Component` (without `<any, any>`) I get complaints about `IntrinsicAttributes` not containing the props I am passing (i.e. I don't seem to be able to just pass through props to the wrapped component):

```
error TS2339: Property 'onClick' does not exist on type
    'IntrinsicAttributes
    & IntrinsicClassAttributes<WithCustomerContext>
    & Readonly<{ children?: React...'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hoc` function should be a generic so that properties can be inferred based on usage:

```
const withAppContext = function (opts) {

    function hoc <P>(WrappedComponent: React.StatelessComponent<P>) : React.ComponentClass<P>
    function hoc <P, T extends React.Component<P, React.ComponentState>, C extends React.ComponentClass<P>>(WrappedComponent: React.ClassType<P, T, C>) : React.ComponentClass<P>
    function hoc <P>(WrappedComponent: any ) : React.ComponentClass<P>
    {
        class WithAppContext extends React.Component<P> {

            context: AppContext;

            render() {
                return React.createElement(WrappedComponent, Object.assign({}, this.props, this.context));
            }
        }
        return WithAppContext;
    };
    return hoc;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<{ prop: string }>{

}
const MyComponentWithContext = withAppContext({})(MyComponent);
let d = <MyComponentWithContext prop =""  />



let GreeterComponent = function (props: {name: string, greeting: string}){
    return <div>{props.greeting} {props.name}!</div> 
}
const GreeterComponentContext = withAppContext({})(GreeterComponent);
let d2 = <GreeterComponentContext  name="" greeting=""  />
```